# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to get a collection select from an another model and I keep getting the above error. Looked everywhere, got rails casts but nothing makes sense.

_form.rb

```
 <%= f.label :city %><br />
 <%= f.collection_select (:share ,:city_id, City.all , :id, :name ) %>
```

It highlights 'form' on the error report

```
<h1>New share</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', shares_path %>
```

Here are my models...

```
class Share
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :type, type: String
  field :summary, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :city, type: String

  embedded_in :city
  has_many :category
end

class City
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :share

  field :name, type: String
  field :country, type: String

  attr_accessible :name, :city_id, :id

end
```

Searched everywhere and I cannot figure it out. It must be something silly.

Comment: I went through it and everything seems right. Nothing seems to be open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is the whitespace after `collection_select`.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all , :id, :name) %>
```

or

```
<%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all , :id, :name %>
```

**EDIT**:

Taking into account that `:share` is your object, I have removed it (see above). The first param is the method:

```
collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Comment: I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out, especially since I had numerous working selects.  Whitespace being significant before a ( is nonsense.  Thank you for the only answer I found on-line.